# URL length in ASP.NET MVC - 260+ characters gives Bad Request - Invalid URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, azure

I have problems with URLs exceeding 260 characters in

- `ASP.NET MVC 4.0`
- `Umbraco CMS`
- `Azure Websites`

IIS chokes and throws the following error:

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
>
> Example URL:
>
> http://example.com/article/123/some-headline-longer-than-260-characters-with-only-text-and-numbers-used

In my case, the URL is *303* characters long without any querystring. Shortening the URL to *260* chars resolve the problem but for me it is not a viable solution. Since I am using ASP.NET I added the following to `web.config` - however, the problem remain even with `maxUrlLength="1024"`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
         <httpRuntime 
              requestValidationMode="4.0" 
              requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;"
              maxUrlLength="1024" 
              maxQueryStringLength="768" 
              relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
      </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

Additional info: All my URLs are kept below the 2000-ish limit (cf. [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?rq=1))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You may need to extend the limit in the registry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am running this on the Azure platform, so this is not an option.

Comment: Well, .Net Framework has a limitation of 260 chars, however you may try to add this in the configuration file for your web role:
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />

Comment: You mean in the web.config? Already did that. Same problem :(

Comment: ANd the last thing I can think about would be to set the maxurl through RequestLimits tag: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: did you ever fix this ?

Comment: @djack109 - I could not find a solution so I shortened the url with a function instead.